# how to disable cursor when hover on url address bar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to disable the cursor when hover on url address bar to avoid editing url text from the address bar.
Is it possible using jQuery or JS.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible, but I might be wrong.

Comment: i confirm, is not possible to access to internal browser functionality for evident security reason

Comment: It is possible. Some banks are using that functionality for security purposes? Recently i saw in some banks websites?

Answer (score 2):

I don't thing you can do this in a regular browser window. But you can open a headless window browser using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

```html
<button onclick="openSecuredWindow()">Open Secured Window</button>
```

```js
function openSecuredWindow() {
  window.open("https://google.com", "", "width=" + window.innerWidth +",height=" + window.innerHeight);
}
```

https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/OZNXZY

Keep attention the user always could copy / paste the url on a regular window.

Comment: Cursor should be disabled when hover on the URL address bar. If we disable cursor users cannot copy the data too.

Comment: I understand that you want this but the in my answer, the cursor will bot be **disabled** but the address bar will be **read only**. I don't think it's possible to **disable** the address bar. If you have a reference, please share the URL.